# iptables shows a warning message but I am unable to solve it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, csf, lfd

When I typed this command in SSH to see rules, it returns the following warning message in iptables. I am wondering what is it and how to solve it. 
iptables -L

```
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning                                  prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* "
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning                                  prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* "
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning                                  prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGDROPOUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 30/                                 min burst 5 LOG level warning uid prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* "
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning                                  uid prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* "
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning                                  uid prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain PORTFLOOD (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning                                  prefix "Firewall: *Port Flood* "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the warning message you are talking about? Do you mean the **warning** word in the lines similar to this?

```
LOG  tcp  --  anywhere  anywhere   limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* "
```

This is not a warning message shown by iptables, but it is part of the output describing your rule. So, `level warning` shows that you have specified `--log-level warning` when you created your `LOG` rule. Nothing to worry about!

Comment: thanks. I didn't specify any rule in IPtables, I use CSF firewall which inserts values in iptable.

Comment: I found that this error is related to messenger service in csf.conf file.